# Unable to find a matching configuration of project

Tags: android, gradle, build

I'm developing app that includes game. My friend sent me gradle project for the game written in Unity. Separately both of them work perfectly. However when I added game as a module to run it from the app I'm receiving build problems. I know it's because of gradle. I tried to find solution but no succeeded. Error I'm receiving is :

```
Could not resolve project :Tower Game.
Required by:
    project :app
 > Unable to find a matching configuration of project :Tower Game:
```

Here are my gradle files :

**GAME**

```
// GENERATED BY UNITY. REMOVE THIS COMMENT TO PREVENT OVERWRITING WHEN EXPORTING AGAIN
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
    }
}

allprojects {
   repositories {
      flatDir {
        dirs 'libs'
      }
   }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion '25.0.2'

    defaultConfig {
        targetSdkVersion 25
        applicationId 'pl.moonlit.projectx.towergame'
    }

    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }

    aaptOptions {
        noCompress '.unity3d', '.ress', '.resource', '.obb'
    }


    buildTypes {
        debug {
            minifyEnabled false
            useProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-unity.txt'
            jniDebuggable true
        }
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            useProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-unity.txt'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }

}
```

**APP**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.maksym.jti"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }

    }
}

dependencies {
   ...
    compile project(path: ':Tower Game')
}
```

Comment: What is your Version of Android Studio?

Comment: It's  Android Studio 3.0.1

Answer (score 1):

Exit existing IDE window.

From AndroidStudio, open the project, reach the directory where project exist.

Inside it select the **settings.gradle** file, it will download all dependencies correctly and open it correctly.